# Doing MySQL query profiling for a website

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I'm trying to setup mysql query profiling as highlighted in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/log-destinations.html

In

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

I added:

```
general_log=1
log_output=FILE
log=/tmp/mysql.log
```

i did

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
Stopping MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting MySQL:                                            [  OK  ]
```

My mysql version is:

```
Server version: 5.0.77 Source distribution
```

But it did not work! No /tmp/mysql.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that `log_output` was introduced in 5.1.

Take a look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output

> Version Introduced    5.1.6

Also, in the article you pointed it says:

> SET GLOBAL log_output='TABLE'; SET GLOBAL general_log='ON';
>
> which has the same effect (note that this is only possible in **5.1**)

Comment: sorry to bother you so late, but i couldnt figure this thing out - please ssee revised quesion

Comment: @Frank, what I'm saying is that you have a version of MySQK 5.0.77 Source distribution that does not support log_output variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of analysing this data would be to enable general query logging (just logging to file by adding `general_log=1` to you my.cnf) and then to analyse the general query log with [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html)

Comment: sorry, i couldnt get it to work - can you have a look and let me know what i'm doing wrong? (see revised quesiton)